# Make a shape with pen tool and colour it (photoshop CC17)

Tags: adobe-photoshop, pen-tool, cc-2017

I am drawing a basic mountain shape using the pen tool creating many different lines for the inside of the shape. Then I need to colour the mountain in and easily change the colour, unfortunately I tried using the paint bucket which gave me awful lines and every time I re-coloured made the quality worse. [image: Mountain]

1. How do I use the pen tool efficiently to get no over hanging lines (so far trial and error if there is a better way please let me know)
2. How do I group all the lines I've use the make the mountain (best way)
3. How do I best colour the mountain

UPDATE: I have managed to combine the shapes now how do I colour it in?[image]

Comment: Although possible in Photoshop, recreating such a graphic would be trivial using Illustrator or other vector image editing software like Inkscape or CorelDraw.  Photoshop isn't really the best software for these kind of graphics.

Answer (score 1):

From your screenshot, I can see that you're using Stroke only and not Fill.

- Select the layer and click on the swatch next to Fill to choose a color and 'fill' the shape. 
  [image]
- I recommend closing all shapes using the Pen tool so that you can control the full shape of the drawings. Meaning, connect the Starting point and the Ending point of each of your shapes.
- For Grouping: You can either use the regular Layer Group command, i.e Select the layers you want to group, go to Layer > New > Group
- Or you can have multiple shapes in one layer = By using the Path Selection tool,  (A) [image], Clicking on a desired Shape, then cutting / pasting on on the desired layer. NOTE: These shapes will have the same layer properties i.e fill and stroke.

Edit: Here are the PSD files as mentioned in the comments. https://we.tl/ompBApYUtE

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately only a few of the shapes filled in, as I am using the outside shape as one of the walls of many of the inside shapes, they are not full shapes themselves some are only lines - Is the best way to fix this with the pen tool?

Comment: In this case: You can either use Layer Clipping Masks or Closed Shapes with Shared Walls. I'd say Clipping Masks are ideal and more efficient way of working.

I've also noticed that your joints overlap - this is because the shapes are Open Shapes with Strokes aligned to the outside of the shape. 

I'll upload a PSD of 'solutions' for the above two points in my original answer.

Comment: Thank you so much problem solved! Appreciate the help!!!